# Open XML Tutorial clarification

Tags: c#, openxml

Trying to learn how to use OOXML to replace tokens win a word document by following this [tutorial](http://www.devx.com/dotnet/Article/42221/0/page/4)

Everything has been going pretty well until I hit this

```
Next, create the custom XML file containing the data for this document, and store it in the package.

Store the custom XML in memory and add placeholders for the actual data.
```

I'm having trouble discerning where to store the custom XML and what he means by storing it in memory.
The author also continues to refer to the file as `package`, so does that mean I should keep the word Template in .zip format?

Comment: Open xml files really are a package. In context he just seems to be referring to a document.

Answer (score 0):

> Next, create the custom XML file containing the data for this document, and store it in the package.

In context, I would suggest the package is the file containing the xml data, which when you load it or display it becomes a document.

Storing it in memory, means loading an object with the data(i.e. xmldocument)